# C# `foreach` loop C equivalent

Tags: c#, c

Any idea how can I do this C# loop in C?

```
foreach (char c in data)
```

loop through a string by character.

Answer (score 4):

There is no `foreach` or equivalent in C. You'll have to use a regular `for` loop:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < strlen(data); ++i)
{
    char c = data[i];
    // ...
}
```

(Assuming `data` is a pointer to a null-terminated string.)

Comment: Significantly faster: `for (size_t s = strlen(data), i = 0; i < s; ++i)`

Comment: @alk Only if `data` is not `const` and/or the compiler used is not able to make this optimization. Any decent modern optimizing compiler should have no trouble with this.